# How to remove cookies,session ID's in redirected URL?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-redirect

I am passing a link through `HttpWebRequest()` and `HttpWebResponse()` methods, I am getting the final response url which contains some cookies(session id) in it.

For example, for this link http://www.1and1.com/

I am getting the following response url: 
http://www.1and1.com/;jsessionid=D94CEA91011FDF30CCA8A8EAC8CE4971.TCpfix243a

When I open http://www.1and1.com/ in a browser, the link in browser address bar doesn't contain this session id value.

How to remove the session id and cookie values from the above response url?

Please help me to get this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `cookieless` property of `sesseionState` section appropriately in web.config. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless.aspx):

> For applications that allow clients that do not support cookies, such
>   as a variety of mobile devices, the session ID may be stored in the
>   URL. The URL option has several drawbacks. It requires that the links
>   on the site be relative and that the page be redirected at the
>   beginning of the session with new query-string values, and it exposes
>   the session ID right in the query string, where it can be picked up
>   for use in a security attack.
>
> You are encouraged to use the cookieless mode only if you need to
>   support clients that lack cookie support.
>
> Session state also supports two additional options: UseDeviceProfile
>   and AutoDetect. The former enables the session-state module to
>   determine what mode (cookie or cookieless) is used on a per-client
>   basis based on the browser capabilities. The AutoDetect option
>   performs a handshake with the browser to verify whether a cookie may
>   be stored, and therefore requires an additional request to make the
>   determination. If you need to support cookieless clients, strongly
>   consider using UseDeviceProfile to generate cookieless URLs only for
>   clients that require them.

Comment: i am using window forms in C# so there is no web.config file i'm using in my program. can you tell me how to make cookieless progrmatically?